# ssl certificate not working on apache linux ec2 instance

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am enabling SSL certificate on my apache linux ecc2 instance.
But when i m adding the following lines

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
#    other configurations
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/mydomain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mydomain.key
</VirtualHost>
```

apache restart is failing.

but when i change in port in above lines to 80.apache starts working.Although i have enabled the port 443 on ec2 admin panel.

I dont know whats the issue.
I have got four certificates from comodo ssl organisation.Out of them i have used only mydomain.crt.Others are intermediate certificates.Do i need to use them as well?

Comment: How is the apache restart failing?  Is there a message in the error log?

Comment: i m sorry.can u please tell me where logs are present or where path is configured.

Comment: got the file.i m gettig an error as in console-Invalid command 'SSLCertificateFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Do you have `mod_ssl` installed?

Comment: i gt an output as ssl_module(shared) when i ran the first command from next answer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the apache SSL module installed.  You can check if it's installed by running:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep ssl
```

If it's not running, try this (assuming standard Amazon Linux AMI):

```
sudo yum install -y mod_ssl
```

or if you're using apache 2.4

```
sudo yum install -y mod24_ssl
```

Comment: ran the first command.gt 
ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK.after running the second command.got-Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.31-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Does the error occur again if you restart apache with `sudo apachectl restart`?

Comment: What is the output of commands `grep ssl_module /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf` and `file /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so`?

Comment: output for first command-/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so output for second-/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=###############################, stripped

Comment: That looks correct.  Can you run `sudo rm /var/log/httpd/*` and restart apache again?  Does the error appear in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` after that?

Comment: output-Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)

Comment: The default SSL configuration may be conflicting with yours.  Try removing your SSL configuration, and just place your certificate file and key in the default locations: `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` and `/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key`.

Comment: again same error-Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)

Comment: What is the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1017)
         port 443 namevhost www.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1017)
         port 443 namevhost *.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1033)
                 wild alias *.domain.com

Comment: shud i send u my file.if u can please review.